# download all the images from dropbox user profile to android phone

Tags: android, dropbox

I am a beginner for android platform.. I'm using dropbox for android api to download all the images from the users dropbox account to the loacal device. I have followed the demo application provided by dropbox and I got the way how to download the images. but now i want to get all the images from dropbox and priview in my application. can anybody help to acheve this.

Answer (score 1):

There are some 3rd-party apps like [dropsync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync&hl=en) for your aid.

Answer (score 1):

Following this documentation https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata
If you send a GET request to this address: `https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/<root>/<path>`
you should get a JSON response with all your files.

```
{
    "size": "0 bytes",
    "hash": "37eb1ba1849d4b0fb0b28caf7ef3af52",
    "bytes": 0,
    "thumb_exists": false,
    "rev": "714f029684fe",
    "modified": "Wed, 27 Apr 2011 22:18:51 +0000",
    "path": "/Public",
    "is_dir": true,
    "icon": "folder_public",
    "root": "dropbox",
    "contents": [
        {
            "size": "0 bytes",
            "rev": "35c1f029684fe",
            "thumb_exists": false,
            "bytes": 0,
            "modified": "Mon, 18 Jul 2011 20:13:43 +0000",
            "client_mtime": "Wed, 20 Apr 2011 16:20:19 +0000",
            "path": "/Public/latest.txt",
            "is_dir": false,
            "icon": "page_white_text",
            "root": "dropbox",
            "mime_type": "text/plain",
            "revision": 220191
        },
        {
            "size": "0 bytes",
            "rev": "35c1f029684fe",
            "thumb_exists": false,
            "bytes": 0,
            "modified": "Mon, 18 Jul 2011 20:13:43 +0000",
            "client_mtime": "Wed, 20 Apr 2011 16:20:19 +0000",
            "path": "/Public/latest.txt",
            "is_dir": false,
            "icon": "page_white_text",
            "root": "dropbox",
            "mime_type": "text/plain",
            "revision": 220191
        }
    ],
    "revision": 29007
}
```

To download the file, please take a look at this address https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET